# Segmentation fault(core dumped) when load model or tensor to GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to use this program; https://github.com/erikwijmans/Pointnet2_PyTorch/tree/master/pointnet2_ops_lib, which is the Pointnet2 model, for other tasks in my experiment, but I found that when I load the model or tensor to GPU, some fault occured.
this is my code:

```
import os
import torch
from pointnet_ops import pointnet2_utils 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] ="0"
a = torch.tensor([1,2])
a = a.cuda()
print(a.device)
```

this program can provide a C++/Cuda extension code for speeding up pointnet2, we can use`python setup.py install to install the code like whl`
this fault occured:

```
segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

and the cuda-gdb information is

```
Starting program: /home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/python test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Detaching after fork from child process 23757]
[New Thread 0x7fff8a725700 (LWP 23796)]
[New Thread 0x7fff89f24700 (LWP 23797)]
[New Thread 0x7fff85723700 (LWP 23798)]
[New Thread 0x7fff82f22700 (LWP 23799)]
[New Thread 0x7fff80721700 (LWP 23800)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7df20700 (LWP 23801)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7b71f700 (LWP 23802)]
[New Thread 0x7fff78f1e700 (LWP 23803)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7671d700 (LWP 23804)]
[New Thread 0x7fff73f1c700 (LWP 23805)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7171b700 (LWP 23806)]
[New Thread 0x7fff6ef1a700 (LWP 23807)]
[New Thread 0x7fff6c719700 (LWP 23808)]
[New Thread 0x7fff69f18700 (LWP 23809)]
[New Thread 0x7fff67717700 (LWP 23810)]
[New Thread 0x7fff64f16700 (LWP 23811)]
[New Thread 0x7fff62715700 (LWP 23812)]
[New Thread 0x7fff5ff14700 (LWP 23813)]
[New Thread 0x7fff5d713700 (LWP 23814)]
[New Thread 0x7fff5af12700 (LWP 23815)]
[New Thread 0x7fff58711700 (LWP 23816)]
[New Thread 0x7fff55f10700 (LWP 23817)]
[New Thread 0x7fff5370f700 (LWP 23818)]
[New Thread 0x7fff50f0e700 (LWP 23819)]
[New Thread 0x7fff4e70d700 (LWP 23820)]
[New Thread 0x7fff4bf0c700 (LWP 23821)]
[New Thread 0x7fff4970b700 (LWP 23822)]
[New Thread 0x7fff46f0a700 (LWP 23823)]
[New Thread 0x7fff44709700 (LWP 23824)]
[New Thread 0x7fff41f08700 (LWP 23825)]
[New Thread 0x7fff3f707700 (LWP 23826)]
[New Thread 0x7fff3cf06700 (LWP 23827)]
[New Thread 0x7fff3a705700 (LWP 23828)]
[New Thread 0x7fff37f04700 (LWP 23829)]
[New Thread 0x7fff35703700 (LWP 23830)]
[New Thread 0x7fff32f02700 (LWP 23831)]
[New Thread 0x7fff30701700 (LWP 23832)]
[New Thread 0x7fff2df00700 (LWP 23833)]
[New Thread 0x7fff2d6ff700 (LWP 23834)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 23836]
[New Thread 0x7fff1da72700 (LWP 23840)]
[New Thread 0x7fff1d271700 (LWP 23841)]
[New Thread 0x7fff1ca70700 (LWP 23842)]

Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff8d85b220 in ?? ()
   from /home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libcudart-a7b20f20.so.11.0
```

my computer setting is

```
cuda:11.1
torch:.1.12.1+cu113(cu111 also tried, but the same fault occured)
```

I have no idea about that, can you give me some advice ?

I want to use this program for some point-cloud based tasks, but when I import the code, I cannot load any model or tensor to GPU in my own code.

Comment: There is very likely a clash between whatever CUDA library components your extension is loading and what Pytorch has already loaded This isn’t anything you are going to resolve here.

Comment: I solved this problem yesterday. I create a new enviroment and use conda to install torch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit, the reconstructed this library pointnet2_ops, then this segmentation fault didn't occur. Maybe my last environment has some problem with pytorch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem yesterday. I create a new enviroment and use `conda` to install torch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit, the reconstructed this library `pointnet2_ops`, then this segmentation fault didn't occur. Maybe my last environment has some problem with pytorch.
Thanks a lot.